# Why in 2D Fourier Transform phase seems to be more "useful" than magnitude?

Tags: image-processing, fourier-transform, phase, reconstruction, magnitude

In 1D signals f(t) (e.g. a sound signal - independent variable t-->time) when we want to use informations from the Fourier transform F(ω) in order to reconstruct the signal, using the magnitude |F(ω)| yields better reults than using <F(ω). In 2D signals f(x,y) (e.g. an image - independent variables x,y-->space coordinates) using <F(ω1,ω2) (usually) yields better results than using |F(ω1,ω2)|. Why is this happening? Is there an intuitive explanation for this result?

Edit: A simple example of what I am referring to is the below, where for image reconstruction phase seems to be more critical than magintude.
[image]

Comment: Phase is often very important in the 1D Fourier Transform as well. An example is the Phase Vocoder for audio pitch change.

Comment: But still most of the times in 1D signals magnitude is more useful than phase, but for reason in 2D signals the opposite seems to happen.

Comment: I agree that magnitude only is useful when we use the FFT for observing a power spectrum but phase is also very important in many other 1D applications where the FFT is used for actual signal processing. Fast correlation and beam steering are other examples. I’d answer below but  I’m less versed in 2D processing.

Comment: It's not clear what you are specifically referring to in terms of "better". Better for what exactly? Signal reconstruction, parameter estimation, etc. Generally speaking, images tend to be sensitive to phase issues when doing processing, which is why linear phase FIRs are typically preferred, though not always. But that doesn't mean there aren't 1D applications that aren't sensitive to phase noise.

Comment: I am referring to signal reconstruction, for a better explanation see the edited part in my question above.

Comment: You ask a general question but give only one example.  Phase is "more important" for images, and for a certain kind of speech compression (convert to an analytic signal, filter, set the envelope to 1, transmit on single-sideband).  But it's less important for other things (analyze a lens for angular resolution, for example).  Are you sure that your generalization is correct?

Comment: @TimWescott I found various similar examples on several notes. I can't find antyhing "special" to these particular examples of images, for all I know they could be some arbitrary images and in most cases this "importance" of phase holds true. So at least for most images this seems to be a strong trend, I just can't explain why.

Comment: “using the magnitude […] yields better reults than using [phase].” (Citation needed) — This is simply not true. In 1D the same happens as in 2D. The location of transitions from one intensity to another is encoded in phase. If you reconstruct a signal after setting the phase in the FT to 0, you will not recognize this signal.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Ok can you give a short explanation/example of how is this sentence true: "The location of transitions from one intensity to another is encoded in phase" ?

Comment: Take any signal, apply FFT, take magnitude (ie set phase to 0), apply IFFT, see result. The exact same thing happens in 1D as in 2D.

Comment: Ok, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not be a very mathematically rigorous answer, but an answer nonetheless. For spatial data (as opposed to multi-channel data), the phase of the FFT encodes the spatial relationship, and therefore the structure, in both dimensions. The magnitude on the other hand encodes the intensity distribution. If you look at the Einstein magnitude with raccoon phase image, clearly a raccoon is visible, but the shading of the image is primarily vertical, ie whole columns seem to have roughly the same intensity value. This correlates more with the shading distribution of the Einstein image. On the other hand, for the Einstein phase raccoon magnitude image, the shading is more horizontal, corresponding to the more horizontal shading in the raccoon image, while Einstein is still clearly visible. The spatial relationship between pixels is likely more important in images than the overall intensity distribution in terms of interpretability.

In 1-D, where the x-axis is time based, the phase encodes the relative temporal relationship of the different components of the signal. For certain applications, this may not be as important for signal reconstruction as the intensity distributions, though I'm sure in some areas like comms, speech recognition, etc, it is quite important.

Comment: I wasn't looking for anything mathematically rigorous anyway, your answer gives some intuition!

Answer (score 1):

> using the magnitude |F(ω)| yields better reults than using <F(ω)

I disagree with the basic premise. For example a simple delay in the time domain ONLY affects the phase in the frequency domain whereas the magnitude remains unaffected

The notion that one is "more important" than the other is IMO misguided. Both are essential parts of the signal representation. Sometimes a certain physical property maps more to one than the other, but in most cases you will need both and so you might as well get used to it.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explained clearly before, I am bascically referring to cases like the one mentioned in the edited part of my question.

Comment: I think you could make an (weak)  argument that the "what" of a feature is mostly magnitude but the "where:" is phase. Recall that translation in the spatial domain is a pure phase shift in the spatial frequency domain. If you want to explore this a bit more, start with something simple: a blob or a line. Move it around and see what changes.

Comment: I thinks it kinda gives an sensation of why that works, thanks!